# grouping hierarchically in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have two entities : Item, and ItemWrapper.

1. ItemWrapper includes Items.
2. ItemWrapper can have an ItemWrapper parent reference

For simplicity, Item is a string "a", "b", ...
ItemWrapper simply contains those items + other ItemWrappers.
They also have their own id.

So basically I have an input list like this :

| id | title | parent_id | items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Wrapper #1 | null | {a,b,c} |
| 2 | Wrapper #2 | null | {x,y,z} |
| 3 | Wrapper #3 | 1 | {w,u} |
| 4 | Wrapper #4 | 1 | null |

I need to write an efficient kotlin function that take this input and returns :

```
{ 
  "Wrapper #1" : { 
      childrenWrappers: [
              "Wrapper #3" : { 
                 childrenWrappers: null, 
                 items: w,u 
               },
              "Wrapper #4" : { 
                 childrenWrappers: null, 
                 items: null
               }  
      ], 
      items: a,b,c 
  },
  "Wrapper #2" : { 
      childrenWrappers: null, 
      items: x,y,z
  }
}
```

The solution can use any data structures or classes,
It doesn't have to be in JSON representation (though I will encode it to json for the API transfer)

Comment: Quote: _So basically I have an input list like this_... Is this list an SQL table? JSON? A Kotlin List?

Comment: the input comes from an SQL, but then I can convert it any data structure.
In the end, this is an API that would have to send it to the client in JSON representation

Comment: Can you add the input to your question like you did with the output? Would be very helpful.

Comment: sorry not sure I understood. I put an example input too. It is a list of objects with 4 variables (id, title, parent_id, items)

Comment: What kind of objects? What is Item? What is ItemWrapper?

Comment: I edited the post.
For simplicity sake, Item is just a string in this example, ItemWrapper simply contains those Items + other ItemWrappers. They also have their own id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data structure looks like the following:

```
data class ItemWrapper(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val items: List<String>,
    val parentId: Int? = null,
)
```

and your expected result data structure looks like this:

```
data class ItemWrapperNode(
    val items: List<String>,
    val childrenWrappers: Map<String, ItemWrapperNode>,
)
```

we can write conversion functions:

```
fun List<ItemWrapper>.toTree(): Map<String, ItemWrapperNode> =
    groupBy { it.parentId }.childrenOf(null)

fun Map<Int?,List<ItemWrapper>>.childrenOf(parentId: Int?): Map<String, ItemWrapperNode> = 
    get(parentId)
        ?.map { it.title to ItemWrapperNode(it.items, childrenOf(it.id)) }
        ?.toMap() ?: emptyMap()
```

Then for a list `itemWrappers` of `ItemWrapper`s
you can call `itemWrappers.toTree()` to obtain the desired output.

If you want to restrict the maximum depth of recursion, we can extend these functions in the following way by introducing an additional parameter `maxDepth` which is decremented on each recursion step:

```
fun List<ItemWrapper>.toTree(maxDepth: Int): Map<String, ItemWrapperNode> =
    groupBy { it.parentId }.childrenOf(null, maxDepth)

fun Map<Int?,List<ItemWrapper>>.childrenOf(parentId: Int?, maxDepth: Int): Map<String, ItemWrapperNode> = 
    if(maxDepth <= 0) emptyMap()
    else get(parentId)
        ?.map { it.title to ItemWrapperNode(it.items, childrenOf(it.id, maxDepth - 1)) }
        ?.toMap() ?: emptyMap()
```

Then, we can for instance write:

```
    val wrappers = listOf(
        ItemWrapper(1, "ItemWrapper #1", listOf("a")),
        ItemWrapper(2, "ItemWrapper #2", listOf("b")),
        ItemWrapper(3, "ItemWrapper #3", listOf("c"), 1),
        ItemWrapper(4, "ItemWrapper #4", listOf("d"), 1),
    )
    println(wrappers.toTree(0))
```

This yields an empty map as result. Using a `maxDepth` of `1` only `ItemWrapper`s #1 and #2 are returned. With `maxDepth` of `2` or higher we obtain all `ItemWrapper`s.

Comment: Great, thank you, Just one question : can I limit the recursion depth ?
So I won't ever hit an infinite loop if someone gives my function an invalid/bad input and then the whole program will fail

Comment: @BVtp I modified the answer, considering also the possibility to restrict the recursion depth.